# Why not Riemann integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x  & ,x\in [0,1]\cap I\\
0 & ,x\in [0,1]\cap Q
\end{array}\right.$ Where $Q$ denotes the set of rationals and $I$ denotes the set of irrationals.

Show that the lower Riemann integral is $0$ and the upper Riemann integral is $1.$
Here is how I tried :
Any partition $J$ of $[0,1] $ contains rationals and irrationals and hence  min value of $f$ on $J$ is $0$ this gives that the lower sum is zero. But I couldn't justify why the upper sum is $1 .$ Can any one give me some hints?

Comment: the upper integral is surely not one, could you go through the statement and look for some tipo?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there is something wrong with this problem:

As $f(x) \leq x$, we have $$\overline{\int_0^1} f(x)dx \leq \overline{\int_0^1} x dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus the upper Riemann integral of $f$ cannot be $1$ (they probably meant $1/2$).

Comment: Probably a typo in the text. If $f(x)$ can only be $0$ or $1$ (instead of $0$ and $x$), I think the upper integral is indeed $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $[a_i,b_i]$ is any interval in the partition, then there is a sequence of irrationals that converges to $b_i$.  So the supremum of $f$ on the interval will be $b_i$.